# unix bash find file directories with 2 explicit file extensions

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to create a small bash script that essentially looks through a directory that includes hundreds of sub directories. in SOME of these subdirectories include a textfile.txt and a htmlfile.html where the names textfile and htmlfile are variable.

I only really care about sub directories that have both the .txt and the .html, all other subdirecories can be ignored.

I then want to list all the .html files and .txt files that are in the same sub directory

this seems like a pretty simple issue to solve but I am at a loss. all I can really get working is a line of code that outputs sub directories that have either a .html file or .txt with no association with the actual sub directory they are in, and I am pretty new at bash scripting so I can't go any further

```
#!/bin/bash

files="$(find ~/file/ -type f -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.html')"

for file in $files
do 
echo $file

done
```

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: I feel like there should be a way to do this with find itself but I'm struggling to think of what that might be at the moment. Which means the best answer I've got (and I don't have time to write it out at the moment) would involve using `-type f \( -name -o -name \) -printf '%h\n'` and then piping it to awk/sort+uniq -c to find results that have more than one output entry.

Comment: @EtanReisner **exactly**! and using `uniq -d` get only duplicated entries, e.g. only where are both files. piping the result to `xargs find ...` for list all files...

Comment: @jm666 You could have a directory with multiple *.html files and no *.txt files or vice versa. If you only print directory names, you would get duplicate lines in both of these cases and you'd end up with false matches.

Comment: @PSkocik no, you cant have multiple files _with the same name_ in the same directory...

Answer (score 2):

The following `find` command looks checks every subdirectory and, if it has **both** `html` and `txt` files, it lists all of them:

```
find . -type d -exec env d={} bash -c 'ls "$d"/*.html &>/dev/null && ls "$d"/*.txt &>/dev/null && ls "$d/"*.{html,txt}' \;
```

Explanation:

- `find . -type d`

  This looks for all subdirectories of the current directory.
- `-exec env d={} bash -c '...' \;`

  This sets the environment variable `d` to the value of the found subdirectory and then executes the bash command that is contained within the single quotes (see below).
- `ls "$d"/*.html &>/dev/null && ls "$d"/*.txt &>/dev/null && ls "$d/"*.{html,txt}`

  This is the bash command that is executed.  It consists of three statements and-ed together.  The first checks to see if directory `d` has any html files.  If so, the second statement runs and it checks to see if there are any txt files.  If so, the last statement is executed and it lists all html and txt files in the directory `d`.

This command is safe for all file and directory names containing spaces, tabs, or other difficult characters.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by searching recursively with the `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **; do
    if [[ -d $file ]]; then
        for sub_file in "$file"/*; do
            case "$sub_file" in
                *.html)
                    html=1;;
                *.txt)
                    txt=1;;
            esac
        done
        [[ $html && $txt ]] && echo "$file"
        html=""
        txt=""
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of -o

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(find ~/file/ -type f -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.html')

for file in $files
do 
echo $file

done
```

Comment: `-or` *is* `-o` just not POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

#A quick peek into a dir to see if there's at least one file that matches pattern
dir_has_file() { dir="$1"; pattern="$2";
  [ -n "$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$pattern" -print -quit)" ]
}

#Assumes there are no newline characters in the filenames, but will behave correctly with subdirectories that match *.html or *.txt
find "$1" -type d|\
  while read d
  do
    dir_has_file "$d" '*.txt' && 
    dir_has_file "$d" '*.html' &&
    #Now print all the matching files
    find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.html'
 done
```

This script takes the root directory to look into as the first argument ($1).

Answer (score 1):

The `test` command is what you need to check for the existence of each file in each of the subdirs:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c "if test -f {}/$file1 -a -f {}/$file2 ; then ls {}/*.{txt,html} ; fi" \;
```

where `$file1` and `$file2` are the two .txt and .html files you are looking for.